# Converting String into Integer and matching to an integer

Tags: python, string, int

been trying this with no luck

```
y = ("586MB Available")
x= re.findall (r'\d+',(y))

>>> x
['586']

if x == 586:
    print ('yes')
else :
    print ("No")
```

No

Comment: "586" != 586. Convert the string to an integer

Comment: ..which, by the way, is done like this: `int(x)`.

Comment: Note that `x` is a list.

Comment: >>> int (x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#94>", line 1, in <module>
    int (x)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is a list of string. You must convert the first element to an int:

```
int(x[0]) == 586
```

or if you want to have an inequality:

```
int(x[0]) < y
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the match, which will always be a string (or bytes, if you're working with bytes) to an integer. Alternatively, compare it to a string (or bytes, again). You also have to actually look within the `list`. The following is probably the easiest way:

```
>>> x = ['586']
>>> '586' in x
True
```

Comment: what if i need to  do like  if y = 600 if x <y then yes else no

Comment: That doesn't make sense for what you're using. `re.findall` is for finding multiple matches, producing a `list`. You can check for membership in a list, but more specific comparisons are ambiguous. Do you want to check whether all the list members don't exceed a certain value?

Comment: apologies ; i will reiterate ; i just want to match if any value entered is equal or less then  like if x = 600 and y = ("586MB Available"), then if x is greater then or less then y